# new function in onclick

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

EDIT: Just an example. I need support for if/else

I want to do this:

```
<button onclick="function() {alert('Hi!');prompt('What can I do for you?', 'make a Sandwich');}">Hello World!</button>
```

Apparently this doesn't work.

Do you know how I could do this?

How can I "call" a new function?

I cannot simply define it in a `<script></script>`-node.

Comment: see the answer ,support for if-else included

Comment: You can use `if...else` in any function as normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to write the functions inside the parameter. It is better to write them on a separate function and then link it with one of the methods listened above. You can still do what you said in the example by using the anonimous function like this:

```
<button onclick='(function(){
    alert("hello world");
    prompt("I am the Doctor","oh yeah");
})()'></button>
```

Comment: `Self Invoking Anonymous Function` or `Immediately Invoked Function Expression`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a `function` to call. You can directly use Javascript code. This is considered bad practice.

```
<button onclick="alert('Hi!'); prompt('What can I do for you?','make a Sandwich');">
    Hello World!
</button>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/bo6wbo4y/)

You can also use `function` as event handler as follow:

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="fnHandler();">
    Hello World!
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function fnHandler() {
    alert('Hi!');
    prompt('What can I do for you?','make a Sandwich');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o9npjvye/)

Using `addEventListener` you can bind events from javascript instead of inline in the HTML(**Recommended**):

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton">
    Hello World!
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hi!');
    prompt('What can I do for you?','make a Sandwich');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o9npjvye/1/)

Comment: we can call it as function also

Comment: Well..that was just an example - what if I want to use if/else?

Comment: just see the other answer @RUB3N for if-else case

Comment: Nope - I don't get past `alert('Hi')`! :/

Comment: I just don't get the prompt - not happening, even if I remove the if/else.
if(true) works fine though

Comment: You can use whatever you want inside the addEventListener, just like any other function

Answer (score 1):

**Updated version for general function because add listner adds uniqueness for click**

```
<button onclick="function_name() id="button">Some Text</button>
```

Now to write the function definition in js

```
function function_name(){ .... statements; }
```

A typical example using this with if-else

```js
<script>
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    if (Calc.Input.value == '' || Calc.Input.value == '0') {
         window.alert("Please enter a number");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button').value=' Justera längd ';
        
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, this is the best thing to do, and it is the most recommended